# not getting emails from my php contact form

Tags: php, forms, email

I have a contact.html form that submits fields to contact.php script; however, I'm not getting the emails on my inbox. yes the to: email address is correct. here the address to the [form web page](http://www.sohotechnology.org/contact.html)
here's the code for contact.php

```
<?php

    $my_email = "jlvazquez825@gmail.com";
    $final_msg = "";

    //validation function
    function validate($data) {
        $data = trim($data); //removing white space and tabs
        $data = stripslashes($data); //removing \
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data); //converting to html
        return $data;
    }

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
            $name = validate($_POST["name"]);
            $email = validate($_POST["email"]);
            $subject = validate($_POST["subject"]);
            $message = validate($_POST["message"]);

    }
    $final_msg += "name: " . $name . "\n" .
                 "email: " . $email . "\n" .
                 "subject: " . $subject . "\n" .
                 "message: ". $message;

    $headers = "From: miatech@sohotechnology.org \r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n";

    if(mail($my_email, $subject, $final_msg, $headers)) {
        echo "<b>Your Message Was Successfuly Sent!... Thanks</b>" . "<br>";
        echo "<b>name: </b>" . $name . "<br>";
        echo "<b>email: </b>" . $email . "<br>";
        echo "<b>subject: </b>" . $subject . "<br>";
        echo "<b>message: </b>" . $message;
    }
    else {
        echo "<b>Your Message Could not be Sent!... Sorry</b>";
    }


?>
```

Comment: Yes, knowing how this is failing would be useful. If it's not already can you set PHP to verbose & update your post w/ some diagnostic information?

Comment: I've mostly programmed in Java, so I'm not an expert in debugging on the browser, I'm just starting to know my way around javscript/php. how could I enable php verbose?... mean while I'm searching for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use bad concatenating operator.

The correct one for strings is `.=`, not `+=`.

```
$final_msg .= '...';
```

Then, everything should be in condition if the form was sent. Now you try to send mail every time the script is loaded, independing on the fact the form was (successfully) sent.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    // sanitize form data, prepare $headers, $final_msg here
    if (mail(...)) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

The condition should be

```
if (filter_var($_POST['mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) &&
    !empty($_POST['name']) && 
    !empty($_POST['subject']) &&
    !empty($_POST['message'])
) {
    //
} else {
    // incomplete form was sent, or data are incorrect
}
```

insteda of `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {`

Comment: how else would the script be executed if not called by the from itself; thus, setting $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']  to POST. which means the script just got data via POST method... right? correct me... oh and I'm dong input checking also through javscript before the form is submitted... I know javascript could be disabled... do you advise checking for input with php too?

Comment: @miatech: it's just a contact form, nothing big, of course. Bad validate data on the server side is a good practice, in plain PHP including error messages on front/end it takes you 2 minutes. About `POST` method: sure, you're right, but in the condition has to be the whole script as I wrote above, not just a part with settings variables as you had.